# SQL: Joining Data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I want to make a SQL query that will link data from two tables, and then relate the data from the second table like this

```
SELECT CustNo AS 'Customer No.', CompanyName, LiasonNo AS 'Liason'  
FROM Customer
```

What I want to do, is relate Liason Number to the Employee Number on another table and then have it list that number as the Employee LastName.

Would I use an inner join to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.CustNo as 'Customer No',
        a.CompanyName,
        b.LastName
FROm    Customer a
        INNER JOIN table2 b 
            ON a.LiasonNo = b.EmployeeNo
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that far, but how would I make the query show EmployeeNo as the Employee.LastName ?

Comment: the query above show the lastname of the employee, can you explain your question more?

Comment: SELECT CustNo ', CompanyName ,Customer.LiasonNo AS 'Liason'  
    FROM Customer
    INNER JOIN Employee
            ON Customer.LiasonNo = Employee.EmpNo 
            AND Employee.EmpNo = Employee.LastName

Comment: Doing this, I get the conversion to smallint error. The only data linking the two tables is the LisasonNo = Employee.EmpNo so from EmpNo, I need it to display the actual last name of the Employee on the employee table.

Comment: and why do you need this `Employee.EmpNo = Employee.LastName`?

Comment: maybe you can add sample data and desired result. it will help a lot.

Comment: I thought it would display the original LiasonNo = EmpNo as the Last name if I set the EmpNo = LastNAme

Comment: Using SELECT Employee.Lastname and then Innerjoin the LiasonNo = EmpNo Thanks!

Comment: `b.LastName`, `b` here is an an alias that i'm using  and it is the same as `tableName.LastName` :D